# Chat em CakePHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, socket, chat

Eu e meu colega desenvolvemos um chat em CakePHP 1.2 (o sistema é um pouco antigo) usando Ajax. Porém o único problema é que ele precisa ficar fazendo requisições ao banco de dados à todo instante, com um intervalo definido, em busca de novas mensagens, mais ou menos como um cara chato pedindo "tem mensagem? Tem mensagem? Tem mensagem?", e isso pode sobrecarregar o servidor se for muito usado, além de que esse método não é uma boa prática. O intervalo, aliás, é bem curto, para uma melhor experiência do usuário.

Enfim, gostaria de alguma alternativa funcional, simples e eficiente. Algo que, ao mandar uma mensagem, o banco já diga ao outro usuário "você tem uma mensagem", o contrário do que acontece.

Pesquisei bastante sobre sockets, mas não soube implementar no código. Pensei também em fazer em AngularJS, mas também sem sucesso. O chat funciona perfeitamente, mas possui esse empecilho.

Prefiro manter sigilo em relação à detalhes sobre o sistema.

Se alguém souber algo, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: NodeJs seria uma boa
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619015/creating-a-private-chat-between-a-key-using-a-node-js-and-socket-io

Comment: Ótimo, vou dar uma pesquisada.

Comment: Andei pesquisando bastante sobre como resolver o problema. Achei alguma coisa sobre Comet, o tal do Ajax Reverso ou Ajax Push, que é o que o chat do Facebook usa (baseando-se nas minhas pesquisas).

Meu problema aqui é como eu vou implementar uma ferramenta baseada em Comet num sistema em CakePHP? Pior ainda, é que preciso salvar todas as conversas num banco de dados PostgreSQL, servidor Apache. Como eu faria isso?